# Why Do Managers not Assign Any Work in Software Company?

Tags: software-industry, management

I've been at a company for 2 years, lets say I am working on Web ECommerce Product System.

Management just moved me to a new Scrum team. We have not done Anything in last 3 weeks, maybe few minutes of programming.

They just pulled me off a previous Scrum team at the same project, in the same office room to work in this new Scrum team. My previous team is very busy and needs a Lot of Help, they are behind.

a) I asked manager, If I can go back to old team and help them out, instead of doing nothing on this new team. He says, know he "wants to wait a few weeks to ramp up". The reason we are not getting work is due to lack of a Product Owner to get tasks from client/business. b) I then, offered to be a part-time Product Owner so we can talk with clients, and acquire software tasks for the development team. Manager still says 'no. ' We have couple other coworkers who have not done anything in the last 6 months either.

I am trying to understand mgmt logic, for paying people to do nothing. For most people, they don't care, and will take the free money, no complaints. For me, I'm little more restless, one of those active people, and rather be doing something. I'm just reading articles and doing small programming tests/projects/tutorials in the time being. Want to do real work eventually.

Before I leave the company as last option, just trying to understand manager's psychology/thinking/political reasons behind doing assigning nothing for me and coworkers. I am on good terms with all the coworkers, and got a 4% raise over last year, so they aren't trying to get rid of us, so it seems.

Comment: Sounds like most government jobs.

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help you. There is no way to read your managements minds over TCP/IP :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle situation when I don't have enough to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/129312/how-to-handle-situation-when-i-dont-have-enough-to-do)

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to understand mgmt logic, for paying people to do nothing.

Lots of possible reasons including the one given that they're waiting on something. But quite often it's a case of use it or lose it. They have an approved budget for x amount of staff, if they say they don't need so many, their budget might go down.

> most people, they don't care, and will take the free money, no complaints.

Most people only go to work for the money.

Comment: ah interesting, so thats why he doesn't want to transfer me back to team with real work, it sounds like twighlight zone/reverse argument, where I was trying to convince my manager to give me work,  usually its opposite, where employees try to get less work

Comment: I've no idea what his agenda is, maybe he wants the other team to have problems so he can add staff/budget.... maybe he's a drug user... maybe he's waiting on a potential project which will need x amount of proven staff for an immediate start. Not much point conjecturing, better just to take him at his word.

Comment: interesting, so really, I have no option, I asked him to move me back, he pretty much refuses, I can signal tactfully that I'm leaving, or just leave, really don't want look for another job during covid times, but whatever thats life, I'm happy I have a job, but I have 2 and 5 year goals I'm trying to reach personally in software, I forecast I wont be doing work for another few months like coworkers,  thanks for the answer, appreciate it

Comment: @alansmith4785 I don't understand why are you unhappy with paid for downtime then. Use this time to develop any skills you want, do some courses, contribute to open source, read a book or simply job hunt while being paid for doing it. Make the best of this situation.

Comment: hi @TymoteuszPaul as I said, Im already doing that, but eventually will want to get a real work, etc in question I noted "I'm just reading articles and doing small programming tests/projects/tutorials"  you should probably only comment if you have answer to the corporate political/psychology about it, thats my only question

Comment: @alansmith4785 if you are after some psychoanalysis of your description of someone then this is highly off topic here, so I'll just VTC for that reason instead.

Comment: feel free to or downvote, don't care, Kilisi provided a great answer anyway, provided insight, about approved budget , or allocation going down, seems reasonable @TymoteuszPaul thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your company is overstaffed compared to the work coming in.

It's easy to make assumptions about poor management, office politics or poor direction from bosses higher up the chain... but there is no answer to this question, we can only give you assumptions about why it might be happening.

I will add 1 possibility that you may find interesting. *(May or may not apply to your situation)*

I live in a large town, not in a city, and there are a number of tech companies. Most of them are average size, and a few really large ones. - My current boss (previously a recruiter in the area) told me that the large tech companies buy up tech staff to prevent the smaller companies competing.

Those developers either get bored and leave, or just stop going to the office and have a free income until the company decides to cut down on staff. - So maybe the company doesn't need you currently, but wants to limit the available candidates for other hiring companies, preventing them from growing and eventually competing.